# Is "they living it up" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs, present-continuous, lyrics

Quote from [Eagles – Hotel California Lyrics | Genius Lyrics](https://genius.com/803150):

> They living it up at the Hotel California

Is *"they living it up"* grammatically correct? Shouldn't it be *"they're living it up"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **they living it up** is grammatically incorrect.

Poetry and songwriting do not always follow "standard" rules of grammar or even usage; the meter and the "feel" of the words are more important. Never assume that any given song lyric is good English.